# How to compute the correlations between submatrices?

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I need to compute the correlations between the columns of my matrix which has more than 800.000 rows in R. I have decided to split this matrix into submatrices (with 60.000 rows for each) and to compute the pairwise correlations between these submatrices.

I use SLURM. What I want to do is to distribute the computation of the correlation between two submatrices on a node of the cluster I use, in order to parallelize.

For the moment, I have created an argument which takes in account the number of columns of the main matrix I want to compute.

For example, with the command line data=data[1:opt$subset,] (in R), I can compute the correlation from my 1st column to the 10.000th : for that, I have set up arrays in my SLurm code : subset=$((SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID*10000)) . I have defined 10 arrays, and so, the first one will compute the compute from the 1st to the 1*10000 th column, the second from the 1st to the 2*10000 = 20 000 th column ....

With this argument data=data[(as.numeric(opt$subset)-4999):opt$subset,] , I can compute the correlations into a block/submatrix with a number of columns defined . For example, if I want to create blocks of 5000 columns , I set up my argument as above and in SLURM , with my arrays : subset=$((SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID*5000)) . So , my first block will correspond from the (1*5000)-4999 = 1st column to the 1*5000=5000th column , the second block will correspond from the (2*5000)-4999 = 5001 th column to the 2*5000 = 10.000 th column ..

My problem is here : the correlations are computed into these blocks independtly . What I want to do is to compute the correlation **between** all of these blocks like this (=pariwise correlation between all the blocks) :

```
        [,1] [,2]
  [1,]    1    1
  [2,]    1    2
  [3,]    1    3
  [4,]    1    4
  [5,]    1    5
  [6,]    1    6
 ...
```

until the block 6 between the block 6.

Any advice ?

Cheers

### R CODE

```
#load packages 
library(compositions)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(optparse)

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = F)

# get options 

option_list = list(
        make_option(c("-s", "--subset"), type="character", default=NULL, help="Input file matrix ")
);

opt_parser= OptionParser(usage = "Usage: %prog -f [FILE]",option_list=option_list, description= "Description:")

opt = parse_args(opt_parser)

#main code

print('Set Up Cores')

cores<-32
options('mc.cores'=cores)
registerDoParallel(cores)

print('Load matrice')

data<-read.table("/home/vipailler/PROJET_M2/raw/truelength2.prok2.uniref2.rares.tsv", sep="\t", h=T, row.names=1)+1

##THIS IS MY ARGUMENT###

#data=data[(as.numeric(opt$subset)-4999):opt$subset,]
data=data[1:opt$subset,]


res <- foreach(i = seq_len(ncol(data)),
 .combine = rbind,
 .multicombine = TRUE,
 .inorder = FALSE,
 .packages = c('data.table', 'doParallel')) %dopar% {
 if((i%%1000)==0){
 print(i)}
 apply(data, 2, function(x) 1 - ((var(data[,i] - x)) / (var(data[,i]) + var(x))))
}
```

### SLURM CODE

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH -o slurmjob-%A-%a.out
#SBATCH --job-name=rho_blocks_5k
#SBATCH --mail-user vincentpailler@hotmail.fr
#SBATCH --partition=normal
#SBATCH --time=1-00:00:00
#SBATCH --mem=250G
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=32
#SBATCH --array=0-10

echo tableau de jobs numero $SLURM_ARRAY_JOB_ID, indices de $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_MIN à $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_MAX

echo $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID

#Set up whatever package we need to run with

module load gcc/8.1.0 openblas/0.3.3 R

# SET UP DIRECTORIES

OUTPUT="$HOME"/PROJET_M2/bin/propr/$(date +"%Y%m%d")_parallel_blocks_32cpus_5000
mkdir -p "$OUTPUT"

export FILENAME=/home/vipailler/PROJET_M2/bin/coefficient_rho.R

subset=$((SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID*10000))

#Run the program

echo "Start job :"`date` >> "$OUTPUT"/temp_"$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID".txt
echo "Start job :"`date`

Rscript $FILENAME --subset $subset  > "$OUTPUT"/"$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID"

echo "Stop job : "`date` >> "$OUTPUT"/temp_"$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID".txt
echo "Stop job : "`date`
```

The output I get is this one :

```
OTU0001     OTU0004    OTU0014    OTU0016    OTU0017      OTU0027
OTU0001  1.00000000  0.96688301 0.80621218 0.16754758 0.40818524  0.155976198
OTU0004  0.96688301  1.00000000 0.81330915 0.18928670 0.43247749  0.187540302
OTU0014  0.80621218  0.81330915 1.00000000 0.23753965 0.57237416  0.222890740
OTU0016  0.16754758  0.18928670 0.23753965 1.00000000 0.64007329  0.775772234
OTU0017  0.40818524  0.43247749 0.57237416 0.64007329 1.00000000  0.445145905
OTU0027  0.15597620  0.18754030 0.22289074 0.77577223 0.44514590  1.000000000
...
```

After, I reaarange my output with :

```
Df<-data.frame(var1=rownames(res)[row(res)[upper.tri(res)]],
        var2=colnames(res)[col(res)[upper.tri(res)]],
        corr=res[upper.tri(res)])
```

in order to get :

```
       var1    var2          corr
1   OTU0001 OTU0004  0.9668830120
2   OTU0001 OTU0014  0.8062121821
3   OTU0004 OTU0014  0.8133091522
4   OTU0001 OTU0016  0.1675475819
5   OTU0004 OTU0016  0.1892866996
6   OTU0014 OTU0016  0.2375396470
7   OTU0001 OTU0017  0.4081852433
8   OTU0004 OTU0017  0.4324774863
...
```

Comment: Hi, why don't you split your matrix column wise? R should be able to calculate the correlation of 800000 vectors, and the reassembling of the results is trivial if you split column wise as opposed to row-wise.

Comment: I might of missed it in your text, but how many columns do you have?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I want to compute the correlations between my columns. I forgot to add " data = t(data) " ! So the matrix I want to work on has 40 rows and more than 800 000 columns

Comment: Can I check your expected outcome (ignoring the actual calculation method for just now) ; do you want the correlation between all of the 800000 columns (i.e. to output a correlation matrix with dimension 800000^2). If so, (I think) you will need ~5000gb to store, regardless of using chunks.

Comment: Yes, I would like to compute the correlations between all of my 800.000 columns. I have edited my question in order to show you my results (It is only on a small subset I got these results)

Comment: Any suggestion or recommendation ?